# Hedging Using Forward Contracts example from Hull's book

Tags: hedging

I am trying to learn futures and options from John Hull's book `Fundamentals of Futures and Options Markets` 9ed. In section 1.8, he has given an example of hedging using forward contracts. Following paragraph appears there:

> Consider next another U.S. company, which we will refer to as ExportCo, that is exporting goods to the United Kingdom and on May 13, 2015, knows that it will receive £30 million three months later. ExportCo can hedge its foreign exchange risk by selling £30 million in the three-month forward market at an exchange rate of 1.5736. This would have the effect of locking in the U.S. dollars to be realized for the pounds at $47,208,000.

I am attaching the table used here.

[image: forward quotes]

How can this ExportCo can sell £30 million if they do not already have it. And how will it help with the foreign exchange risk ? I am not understanding this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forward contract is a promise to do something in the future. You have to be certain that you will be able to deliver on that deal, even if you take a loss by doing so; if you can't, you have no business signing the contract. In this case presumably the company *can* be certain it will be able to deliver $30M worth of goods in three months; that is simply an assumption in this example. The forward contract is just being used to shift when the payment occurs, presumably at some cost since the buyer is accepting the risk you are avoiding.